# How to predict Total Hours needed with List as Input?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, predictive-modeling

I am struggling with the problem I am facing:
I have a dataset of different products (Cars) that have certain Work Orders open at a given time. I know from historical data how much time this work in **TOTAL** has caused.
Now I want to predict it for another Car (e.g. Car 3).

[image]

Which type of algorithm, regression shall I use for this?

My idea was to transform this row based dataset into column based with binary values e.g. Brake: 0/1, Screen 0/1.. But then I will have lots of Inputs as the number of possible Inputs is 100-200..

Comment: The relation between Car3 and the other cars can't be extracted from the data. What if Car3 is totally different from Car1 and Car2? How would your model know? Instead of the model of the car, you could have defining characteristics of it, like brand, type of fuel, age of the car.

Comment: Those are further inputs for sure, but the main driver are the open work orders

Comment: I agree with @noe (+1 for the comment). Indeed the problem is poorly stated, and the `Car` column gives you no information to learn from. Moreover, if you transform your data as you have proposed, what if a new car brand arrives for which you have no information in any of the resulting columns (after your transformation)? You must at least expand the *implicit* information in the `Car` to have some information to learn from (i.e., adding some columns).

Comment: Guys, Car column is not an input variable! it is the case column

Comment: It would be best if you modified your question because it is poorly stated; in particular, *now I want to predict it for another Car (e.g. Car 3)* makes no sense. As we pointed out and, more importantly, suggested, adding more information about each particular car is preferable.

Comment: Well, what I want is predict the Total Hours based on the open work orders by looking/Training historical data and with only the open work orders as input.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the problem you described, it sounds like you want to predict the total hours needed for a given set of work orders on a new car (Car 3) based on historical data.

Since you want to predict a continuous value (total hours needed), a regression algorithm would be a good choice.

One approach you can take to handle the large number of inputs is to use a feature selection technique to select the most relevant inputs (work orders) that have the most impact on the total hours needed. This will reduce the number of inputs and make the model more efficient.

You can use techniques like Lasso regression, Ridge Regression, Random Forest and Recursive Feature elimination etc for feature selection.

Another approach is to use dimensionality reduction techniques like PCA (Principal component analysis) which will reduce the number of input features by creating new features that are linear combinations of the original inputs.

It's also worth noting that when you are dealing with a large number of inputs, it's important to have a large enough dataset to train your model effectively, otherwise, the model may not be able to generalize well to new data.

In summary, you can use a regression algorithm to predict total hours needed, and use feature selection or dimensionality reduction techniques to handle the large number of inputs.

Comment: So you think I need to transform the items to binary input variables and reduce them? Are there alternatives to it?

Comment: You can experiment and you have to find out what's the best method for this problem

Comment: Thats exactly my problem: i am looking for approaches that I can test